# WordPress Ajax in plugin returning 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins

I've read a ton of similar questions, but can't seem to figure out the problem I'm having.  Here's my plugin file (simplified just to get a return value):

```
// add JS file
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_patient_login_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajax_patient_login_enqueue_scripts() {
     wp_enqueue_script( 'patient-login-ajax-scripts', plugins_url( '/js/scripts.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );

     // this sets up hooks that the javascript file can use to access ajax calls
     wp_localize_script( 'patient-login-ajax-scripts', 'patientlogin', array(
         'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
     ));
}

// login user
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_client_login', 'client_login' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_client_login', 'client_login' );
function client_login() {
    return 123;
}
```

My JavaScript is loading correctly, because I'm able to step through it in the browser.  The problem seems to come down to its ability to access the action "client_login".  Here's the JS:

```
// handle login
function handleLogin() {
     $.ajax({
        url: patientlogin.ajax_url,
        data: { action: 'client_login' },
        success: function( result ) {
            // other functions...
        }
    });
}
```

'result' is always 0, and I can't figure out why. The browser seems to find the ajax_url without any problem, but it can't seem to find the action.  I've probably missed something obvious, but I can't see it, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback function is returning a value. A callback should output a value instead. You need to `echo` 123 instead of returning it. Finally, call `wp_die()`.

Example:

```
function client_login() {
    echo 123;
    wp_die();
}
```

Documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins